# Compare Two Dataframes rows at specific columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stock

I have a list of DataFrames, in each DataFrame each row is a unique day, and the columns represent prices in the market. Each element in the list is a different stock. I want to compare each stock to each other and look at their respective day cells and determine if they are both positive values in the cell or negative. I then want to have a running score for each stock to each stock, if the values are both positive then the running score is increased and if it is negative the running score decreases.

This is my code so far - I think the main area that I am making mistakes is how to grab the specific cells

```
    def DetermineScoreArray(size):
scoreMatrix = np.zeros((size,size))
scoreArray = []
for stock_i in range(0,size):
    for stock_j in range(0,size):
        for day in range(0,STOCK_LEN):
            if(stock_i != stock_j):
                if ListOfFiles[stock_i].loc[day, "% C-O'"] > 0 and ListOfFiles[stock_j].loc[day, "% C-O'"] > 0:
                    scoreMatrix[stock_i][stock_j] += 1
                elif ListOfFiles[stock_i].loc[day, "% C-O'"] < 0 and ListOfFiles[stock_j].loc[day, "% C-O'"] < 0:
                    scoreMatrix[stock_i][stock_j] += 0.5
                else:
                    scoreMatrix[stock_i][stock_j] -= 1
            else:
                scoreMatrix[stock_i][stock_j] == 0

for stock_i in range(0,size):
    max = ""
    for stock_j in range(0,size):
        if(scoreMatrix[stock_i][stock_j] > max):
            max = stock_j
    scoreArray.append(max)
print(scoreArray)
```

Just to explain the code a bit - 
size is the number of DataFrames I have in the ListOfFiles list, 
I created a scoreMatrix to keep track of the running scores for each stock and how it compares to another stock
the scoreArray is the highest scores that a specific stock and I hope to store the corresponding stock in that array
so I first loop through each stock and each time I compare it to all the other stock, thats the first 2 for loops
inside each of these comparisons I want to calculate the score for each day so I have another for loop
then I dont want to compare 1 stock to itself, and then finally I have a few conditions on the stocks themselves and how they change the score. 
this is mostly where I think my mistake is, I think I am not using the proper syntax for getting the proper cell.

Thanks in advance

I am new to pandas so please go easy on me.

Comment: Please take the time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To add to above comment. Please do not *tell* us your data structure but *show* us an sample.